# Where can I find Herons?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

In Assassins Creed Origins where can I find Herons at? I've been looking near water and I cannot seem to find any do they only appear at a certain time of the day? Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to use Senu to spot resources, this makes things much easier.

Comment: @DavidYell Senu doesn't highlight birds (herons, flamingos), since they don't provide resources (leather, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herons are black and white birds that can be found near a river or bodies of water. They can be seen flying in the air, so you can take them out with your bow. Click [here](http://www.gameskinny.com/gjovr/how-to-find-heron-feathers-in-assassins-creed-origins) for more info.